# Uncheck "Use Default Value" Check in the Website Scope Magento 2

Tags: backend, magento2, magento-2.3, magento-2.0, magento2.4

In the Magento Backend I want to implement the logic i.e. I have one custom module at the location Stores > Configuration > Custom Module

I can see I have multiple websites and stores. I want to implement one logic i.e. when I click on Website view from the scope, the "Use Default Value" checkbox must be unchecked by default.

Any idea on the same please answer

Answer (score 0):

We don't need any manual coding for this. Once we will set the value at website and store level it will automatically uncheck the Default Value Check from the configuration